# PdfReader not opened with owner password

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-reader

I am using iTextSharp version 4.1.6.0 and my code throws the "PdfReader not opened with owner password" exception. The strange thing is that I can open all single PDF files, but on merging them it fails. Following other threads I was trying:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

but this parameter is not accepted and I get:

```
'PDFReader' does not contain a definition for 'unethicalreading'
```

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a look at the source of `PdfReader` [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs), the static property `unethicalreading` is available after v5.0.2.

> but on merging them it fails

Yes, because copying and merging are operations that require special permissions which require the user/owner password.